# node net.js Server()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I checked the `createServer()` function in net.js:

```
exports.createServer = function() {
return new Server(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
};
```

I checked the source code of Server() function in net.js and found that

```
function Server(/* [ options, ] listener */) {
  if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);

  var self = this;
  // ......
}
```

When we call the `createServer()` function, that function will call `new Server()`. And inside the `Server()` function, since `this` is not an instance of Server, it will call `new Server()` again. Based on my understanding, the new Server() function will fall into an infinite loop since it keeps calling new Server().  Could someone please explain what I am wrong here?

If Quentin is right, then the `if` statement can never be true since `new Server()` has been called in the `createServer()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common pattern in JavaScript. Take the following:

```
function MyInst(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

var inst = MyInst(a, b);
```

You will have effectively appended the properties `a` and `b` to the `global` Object. So instead you have a conditional to check if the call is a proper constructor call:

```
function MyInst(a, b) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyInst))
    return new MyInst(a, b);
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

// Now I can be lazy and not use "new"
var inst0 = MyInst(a, b);
// Or I can still use it properly
var inst1 = new MyInst(a, b);
```

The same thing is being done in `net.Server()`. Basically protecting people from themselves and always making sure the object context is an instance of itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `if` statement before the `return new Server` statement.

It looks like it is there to recover from people calling the `Server` function without doing as as a constructor function (i.e. with `new`).

Comment: Yes, I noticed there's an if statement. But when we don't have an instance of Server, we will fall into an infinite loop. Right?

Comment: Wrong. There is a `new` between `return` and `Server` (so it will go down one level and then the `if` statement will no longer be true)

Comment: I just found that `createServer()` in net.js: 'exports.createServer = function() {
  return new Server(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
};' According to your explaination, the `if` statement can never be true, since whenever you create a server, you will call `new Server()` and when it goes into `Server()` function, the `if` statement is always true.